# Separating family of functions for measures

Tags: measure-theory

Given a family $X$ of real-valued functions $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ on some set $\Omega$, consider the smallest $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$ making all $f\in X$ measurable with respect to the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.

I am wondering if there is a sufficient condition for the equality $\int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu=\int f\,\mathrm{d}\nu$ for every $f\in X$ to imply $\mu=\nu$.
Hereby, both $\mu$ and $\nu$ are countably additive measures such that for every
nonnegative $f\in X$ we have $\int f\,\mathrm{d}\mu<\infty$ (for $\nu$ resp.).
I am guessing that $X$ has to be large enough, but on the other hand this enlarges $\sigma(X)$ as well so i am not sure about that.

Comment: On which sigma algebra are $\mu$ and $\nu$ defined? It is probably necessary that $\sigma(X)$ "almost" generates this sigma algebra, i.e. that for every $M$ in that sigma algebra there are $K,L \in \sigma (X)$ with $\mu (K) =\mu (M)=\mu(L)$.

Comment: They are indeed defined on $\sigma(X)$.